# How to import a WP backup website into another Wordpress hosting?

Tags: wp-query, static-website

Hi from one of my client i got a **wp.26_73670.2020-03-05_04-54-53.tar**

This **TAR** file nothing but a backup of a WP website and when i unzip the file it contain following folder

[image]

Here **mystatcsite** folder contain my website related data

[image]

Now issue is that i bought new web-hosting and installed Wordpress in that server but i dont have any idea how to run my old website in this new web hosting server via installed WP. Its a static website so no database in my case.

1. Can i directly import the website via Filezilla into WP any folder and it start working ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can unzip the TAR file and extract the files into your root folder where you want WordPress installed.  But that is only half of your setup.  The other half is the database.

You will need to export your database from the current site and then import it into your new site.  A lot of hosts offer an online tool called phpMyAdmin which you can use to export and import the database.

After that is done you may need to change the [site url](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/), if that is changing.

There are plenty of guides online that will walk you through step by step if you need it.

[WordPress Info](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/)

[Step by Step](https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/)

There are also plenty of plugins out there that will help with the site migration, just search for "WordPress Migration Plugin".

Comment: Thanks for your reply,EVen for static site like me also need to import/export database as well and in my server two places i saw WP folders. one `/etc/wordpress` and `/usr/share/wordpress` which one used to import the tar file?

Comment: Sorry I think I mis-understood what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to run your static site from inside of the WordPress install?

Comment: Look like i am not able to tell it clearly .My previous website also a WP site but i took backup of site via 'Softclulous->Backup' and i got the backup of the site as a tar folder.Now i bought a new server and installed WP there now i want to run my backup site into this new WP installation .Hope it clear the doubt.

Comment: OK, so my above answer is correct.  You just need to import your stuff into the new site.  Import your files and database.

Comment: So where i have to unzip the tar file `/etc/wordpress` OR `/usr/share/wordpress`

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on your host, look for where the current WP install is setup.  Typically inside of /public_html.  A lot of hosts will set this up for you for free, you just provide them the backup and they do the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105266/discussion-between-subodh-and-riddlemethis).